# Flutter Firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-navigation

I am building a Social media like app with messaging 
.
and I am using firebase messaging to push notification to users when other users send them messages 
I want to open the chat screen when the user clicks the message notification if it is not on the top of the navigator stack

```
// this will run when the user clicks the message notification 
// i want to open the chat screen with the user if it is not on the top of the navigator stack
void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
  if (message == null) return;
  // here do your navigation and whatever your want
  if (navigatorKey.currentContext == null) return;
  String? storeId = message.data['storeId'];
  //? here handle routing the message to chat screen or to message
  if (storeId == null) return;
  //? skip the message foreground message
    // here push to the chat screen
    MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel.fromJson(message.data);
    StoreModel? model = ProviderCalls.storePF(navigatorKey.currentContext!)
        .stores
        .cast()
        .firstWhere(
          (p0) => p0.id == messageModel.storeId,
          orElse: () => null,
        );
    if (model == null) return;

    AppRoutes.push(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        StoreChatScreen(
          storeModel: model,
          userId: _getUserId(model, messageModel),
        ));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You can get that payload at here and you can use that payload for redirect user to that particular screen that was mentioned in that site also